# Trying to get JSF(Faces) working within Spring WebFlow

Tags: jsf, spring-mvc, jsf-2, spring-webflow

I been trying to add some JSF(Face) code into my Spring Webflow project but I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FacesContext has not been initialized within the current Web Flow request. Check the configuration for your <webflow:flow-executor>. For JSF you will need FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener configured as one of its flow execution listeners.
```

Here is my flow.xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.2.xsd">

    <!-- Executes flows: the central entry point into the Spring Web Flow system -->
    <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
        <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
            <webflow:listener ref="facesContextListener"/>
        </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
    </webflow:flow-executor>

    <!-- The registry of executable flow definitions -->
    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF">
        <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="**/*-flow.xml" />
    </webflow:flow-registry>

    <!-- Configures the Spring Web Flow JSF integration -->
    <faces:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" />

    <!-- A listener maintain one FacesContext instance per Web Flow request. -->
    <bean id="facesContextListener" 
        class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener" />  

</beans>
```

and here is my flow:

```
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
                          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <var name="customer" class="org.smith.webflowtemplate.domain.Customer"/>


    <view-state id="checkbox-input" model="customer" >
            <transition on="submit" to="preview" validate="false"/>
            <transition on="cancel" to="thanks" validate="false"/>
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="preview"  model="customer">
                <transition on="accept" to="endState"/>
     </view-state>

    <end-state id="endState" view="/index.jsp"  />

</flow>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a Faces Context listener like this:

```
<flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
        <flow-execution-listeners>
            <listener ref="facesContextListener" />
        </flow-execution-listeners>
</flow-executor>

<beans:bean id="facesContextListener" class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener" />
```

Comment: Did it get rid of the exception or are you getting the same exception again.

Comment: Same here..do not edit the question with updates. Just add an update section leaving the previous entry untouched and add what you have changed based of my anwser.