# getting FlowExecutionRestorationFailureException in spring web flow

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-mvc, primefaces, spring-webflow

I am getting FlowExecutionRestorationFailureException exception when i am closing the tab of application.

We have a application developed in primeafaces 3.4.2 and spring web flow 2.3.1.

In this application we have a Home Screen (first screen display after login) and at this screen we have a Account link(CommandLink).

When we click on Search link **other tab** (Now we have two tabs- 1. Home Screen 2. Account) is open with Account detail and on that screen we have Billing button. we are navigating to Billing screen on click of Billing button.

After that we are closing the Billing screen tab by clicking the close icon of tab.

But still we have other tab having Home Screen, we click the Account link.

Follow the same step 7-8 times. After that we are getting FlowExecutionRestorationFailureException exception.

**Flow Snap Shot config:**

```
    webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
    <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
        <webflow:listener ref="facesContextListener" />
        <webflow:listener ref="securityFlowExecutionListener" />
    </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>     
    <webflow:flow-execution-repository max-executions="0" max-execution-snapshots="15" />       
</webflow:flow-executor>
```

**Exception Trace:**
type Exception report
message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.FlowExecutionRestorationFailureException: A problem occurred restoring the flow execution with key 'e1s1'
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.repository.FlowExecutionRestorationFailureException: A problem occurred restoring the flow execution with key 'e1s1'
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:88)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)

Some Detail about Flow:
[image: Flow Detials]
 I tried to end billing sub flow and Home sub flow, but when i click the Account Link its opening Home screen again and receive the same exception later.

Please advise/suggest me.

Comment: Are you specifying the flowExecutionKey and flowId in each of these screens? They are the ones which restores/resumes the flow if paused.

Comment: no, I am not specifying flowexcecutionkey and flowId in screens as Once a flow execution is created Webflow assigns it a flow execution key.

Comment: Where is this  "Search link other tab"  located? What steps we need to repeat? Can you make it clear.

Comment: Search is a <p:commandLink> at Home screen. Steps: 1. In this application we have a Home Screen (first screen display after login) and at this screen we have a Account link(CommandLink).

2. When we click on Search link other tab (Now we have two tabs- 1. Home Screen 2. Account) is open with Account detail and on that screen we have Billing button. we are navigating to Billing screen on click of Billing button.

3. After that we are closing the Billing screen tab by clicking the close icon of tab.

4. But still we have other tab having Home Screen, we click the Account link.

Comment: Let me know how it goes with the below change.

Comment: Account Search link is <h:commandButton>. its looks like that :       <h:commandLink styleClass="ux_link_text" action="accountSearch" 
value="Account Search" target="_blank"/>

Comment: Thanks Prasad! I tried to include <input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}"> in all the form in xhtml files, but still I am getting same exception. I didn't pass this by javascript, i just included in all forms as hidden variable.

Answer (score 1):

See your configuration max-executions="0" max-execution-snapshots="15" is the key here.

"max-executions" attribute specifies as to how many flow execution can be spawn concurrently.

Each request for flow execution creates a snap shot of its state. "max-execution-snapshots" attribute specifies as to how many of these states can be stored. Once the limit is reached the oldest one will be removed first.
If you are opening multiple tabs, and all are associated with the same execution, they are having the common snapshot limit.

As per this configuration max-executions="0" and max-execution-snapshots="15": You can store 15 snap shots. So when you repeat your steps of opening multiple tabs and closing them, at some point snapshot limit of 15 is reached and snapshot s1 is removed and when you try to access the link with old snapshot(e1s1 by clicking on account link) it's not there anymore.

To overcome this change your configuration something like:

max-executions="5" max-execution-snapshots="25"

Comment: After applying changes suggested by you i.e <webflow:flow-execution-repository max-executions="5" max-execution-snapshots="25" />,
now when we are clicking Search Link(after repeating all steps first time), sometime it's opening Home screen again i.e wrong its hould open Search screen but sometimes it's 
continuing the correct state(open Serarch Screen).

Comment: Can i override the flow-execution-repository of spring and will put one condition to check if its belongs to home screen, than don't remove the snapshot from the map?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Maybe you were missing the registry-Attribute. At least this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13056141/5449497) configuration worked for me:

```
<webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry"> 
  <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
    <webflow:listener ref="facesContextListener" />
  </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
</webflow:flow-executor>

<bean id="facesContextListener" class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener" />
```